# ifsym package problem

Tags: symbols, packages, margins

I am using a template from the following web-page:
[Template of Latex](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

I came up with a problem where I want to use "ifsym" package symbols and I could not get them. Actually, I want to use a symbols to present rain and error. Suggestions are welcome.

Moreover, how can I extend the margins a little bit more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is not very clear (it always helps if you include a document that shows the problem) but this

[image]

Is a document that increases the text width by 2cm and uses a Rain symbol.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[weather]{ifsym}

\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1cm}

\begin{document}


It's going to \Rain\ today.

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I modify the headers, with respect to the page margins?

Comment: @aliamidi We like to keep one question focused on one issue. Have a look at the [`geometry` package](http://texdoc.net/pkg/geometry) and ask a new question if the documentation doesn’t help.